# how do I convert my git project into a fork of another project

Tags: git

hi everyone I have a question that I hope has also a simple answer.
Because I was not thinking straight, maybe I also did not know about it at the time, I cloned a project from another project when in fact what I really wanted was to do a fork of the original project.

My projects do not have many changes with them and I want to keep track of the changes on the upstream.

Is there any option of after creating a clone convert this project into a fork of the parent?
Meaning I want to be able to define the upstream as the original project and just merge whatever change I have done after into my new project.

Is this possible?

so let's say i have original project-source
I created project-source-v2

I want now to make project-source-v2 as a fork of project-source

I'm trying something like this: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork but I'm failing when it comes to actually then do the pull and push it seems to not recognize the upstream

(master is only available in the upstream)

```
$ git pull master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: You could fork the original repo and then add two remotes to your clone: `origin` and `fork`. `origin` would be the original repo and `fork` would be your fork.

Comment: I can do something simple, just create another fork, copy my things on top of the fork and then remove my current repo, but I wanted to know if there is a way that once you create a repo to change it and make it has a fork.

Comment: If you're talking about GitHub, then no, there's no way to do that AFAIK.

Comment: actually I'm talking about bitbucket but I thought this were just implementations of git

Comment: Git doesn't have a concept of "forks" (it just has clones and remotes). BitBucket doesn't allow this either AFAIK.